# I'm developing an application in Android , that should detect when an user hasn't touch physically his mobil device for a while

Tags: android, system

To do I need to know how I can detect any touch on the screen or buttons on the device by the user. This actions should be detecting from my application running in the background.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Please be more descriptive in what you want to achieve. Add as much information as possible. Avoid saying thank you and please (especially in the title, please change that)

Comment: what you mean by turn on and off. did you mean that switch on and off or screen wake up and device locked.

Comment: When I said "If device was turn On or Off" I mean if screen was asleep or device was wake up but this action was run by user.                           The goal I want to get is to be able to watch this action only run by user but not on my app , on the screen of device, I don't want the user interactive with my app. My app should watch only this kind of action.